# How to make subviews stay the same size when expanding UITableVewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which I have UITableViewCells that I made expand and contract with beginUpdates and endUpdates. This is a UITableViewCell subclass that I have loaded from an XIB file. This contains a UIImageView that has an image that I download from the internet. But, when the cell expands, the image will not retain its aspect ratio and expand the same amount as the cell does. How can I make it so the image retains its aspect ratio and does not change size? Also, I am not using AutoLayout in any of my XIB files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because the Bitmap layer change when your view changes bounds size.

Try to set the `contentMode` property of your UIImageView to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode

Comment: This fixes the resizing of the image view, but now the image view gets moved down. Is there any way to make it so the origin of the image view is fixed too?

Comment: Never mind, I was able to get it working with UIViewContentModeTop. Thanks.